# Can GCC optimize code size for functions with the same body?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I'm debugging a C++ program with GDB and faced that different functions turned out to be the same. Here is what I mean by that:

`some.hpp`

```
class Base{
   virtual bool foo() const;
   virtual bool bar() const;
}
```

`some.cpp`

```
bool Base::foo() const {
  return false;
}

bool Base::bar() const {
  return false;
}
```

The problem is that in gdb I see the following:

```
(gdb) p someBaseObject->foo
$1 = {bool (const Base * const)} 0xdeadf00d <Base::foo() const>
(gdb) p someBaseObject->bar
$2 = {bool (const Base * const)} 0xdeadf00d <Base::foo() const>
```

I suppose GCC optimizes those two functions to save code size. Does it? This complicates debugging though...

Comment: what is `someBaseObject->for`? It should be `someBaseObject->foo`?

Comment: which options did you use for compiling ?

Comment: what the compilation flags are?

Comment: `0xdeadf00d` looks like some kind of [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Are you sure `someBaseObject` is valid?

Comment: @yaodav Unfortuantely I don't know :(. I have a compiled binary with debug symbols installed in a separate package.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I replaced the actual address intentianally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wonder how something is compiled it is often very helpful to have a look at the compiler explorer.

Here is your code (with calls to both functions)
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/g2hfcA

When enabling the compiler flag for "inter-procedural optimization Identical Code Folding" `-fipa-icf` you allow the compiler to replace identical functions. This leads to `bar` disappearing in the assembly. If you compile with `-O3` this gets activated too.

[GCC doc on `-fipa-icf`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> -fipa-icf:
>
> Perform Identical Code Folding for functions and read-only variables. The optimization reduces code size and may disturb unwind
>   stacks by replacing a function by equivalent one with a different
>   name. The optimization works more effectively with link-time
>   optimization enabled.
>
> Although the behavior is similar to the Gold Linker’s ICF
>   optimization, GCC ICF works on different levels and thus the
>   optimizations are not same - there are equivalences that are found
>   only by GCC and equivalences found only by Gold.
>
> This flag is enabled by default at -O2 and -Os.